# Unhex a value Conversion - SQL

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, hex, azure-synapse

I have a Query that allows me to hex a certain value, but I cannot seem to Unhex it?
how should I do this ?

--> this samplecode  runs in MySQL and does the Hex, what I need, is what should do the opposite

```
CONCAT(
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE ,4,1)),
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,3,1)),
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,2,1)),
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,1,1)), '-',
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,6,1)),
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,5,1)), '-',
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,8,1)),
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,7,1)), '-',
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,9,2)), '-',
            HEX(SUBSTRING(SUBJECT_CODE,11,6))) as SUBJECT_CODE,
```

Example of a Hexed Value : 34383963-7271-3261-3378-367273356F61
Original and expected Value : c984qra23x6rs5oa2gqk5y56kab7mkpr

I am FYI , Using Synapse serverless to run this, so not MySQL anymore
Update --> a Pyspark Solution would also be of great help!

Any help here ? :/

Robbe

Comment: _Matching_ sample data and expected result makes much more sense. (Unhex to what?)

Comment: Hi, well, I wish I could help! but thats just my main issue :D

Comment: Is it one-byte characters (e.g. latin1?)

Comment: Updated the post with an origial and expected value

Answer (score 0):

You might use `UNHEX()`. Please try this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX(REPLACE(SUBJECT_CODE, '-', '')), CHAR(36)) as SUBJECT_CODE_UNHEXED
FROM your_table_name;
```

Comment: Hi, 
I indeed saw that option, but tha is not available in Syanapse!